# Regression analysis for a big set of data

Tags: regression, dataset, k-means

Well, it's my first post but I have been struggling hard with this problem so I had to look after help.

The problem:

I have a high set of data like this one (black dot are the data):[image]

I have to find any kind of correlation between de UTS(ultimate tensile strength or Rm) and the Carbon equivalent (Ceq) of steels.

I have tried grouping the data with kmean-s as there are no outliers (data is from real trials that have some kind of variance) and then perform a regression analysis. The thing is the centroids are somewhat displaced (obviously) from the center of the data in the clusters so the error in the prediction is quite big afterwards.
Someone in my office suggested making a filter to take something like the mean, or weight the data as the 1% Ceq are to be considered in the regression, but I don't know.

I don't know how to proceed and I would like any possible hint as to how to approach this problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do a regression from the start?  It's not clear that there are multiple lines here to justify the clustering.  Alternately, you can use a non-parametric technique like [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) to replace the clustering and the regression.